# Code to change font color for text that is a link

Tags: javascript, colors

I have 2 lines of code in my JavaScript to dynamically change colors, one to change the background color of a table row and the other to change the font color:

```
rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
rows[i].style.color = 'white'
```

I need one more line of code to change the font color specifically when it is a hyperlink.  I tried:

```
rows[i].style.link.color = 'white'
```

and several other variations but I can't get the linked font colors to change.  Can anyone help with this please?  Thanks.

Full code:

```
var INTENDED_MONTH = 7 //August
// INTENDED_MONTH is zero-relative
now = new Date().getDate(),
rows = document.getElementById('scripture').rows;
if (new Date().getMonth() != INTENDED_MONTH) {
    // need a value here less than 1, or the box for the first of the month will be in Red
    now = 0.5
};
for (var i = 0, rl = rows.length; i < rl; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0, cl = cells.length; j < cl; j++) {
        if (cells[j].nodeName == 'TD'
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue != ''
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            rows[i].style.color = 'white'
            rows[i].style.a.color = 'white'
            $('html,body').delay(500).animate({ scrollTop: rows[i].offsetTop }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using CSS for this?

Comment: css code is being used within the javascript.  It all works, all I am looking for is the final command to change linked text colors.  Do you know what that is?

Comment: I meant shouldn't you be handling CSS code inside the `style` tags? It's recommended that CSS/JS/HTML be separately managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using CSS?

```
tr{
   backgorund:red;
   color:white;
}
tr a{
   color:white;
}
```

If you need JavaScript, you can use

```
var els=rows[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
   els[i].style.color = 'white';
}
```

**Edit:**

You can also use

```
tr a{
   color:inherit;
}
```

and then when you do

```
rows[i].style.color = 'white'
```

anchors' color will be the same as row's color - white -.

**Edit 2:**

As I said in my comment, even if you create the links with javascript, they are HTML elements so CSS affects them.

But the problem is that the rule

```
table.hovertable a:link, table.hovertable a:visited, table.hovertable a:hover, table.hovertable a:active {
    color: black;
}
```

overrides

```
table.hovertable tr a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Then, you need

```
table.hovertable tr a:link {
    color: inherit;
}
```

which has the selector `:link`, so both rules have the same selectors and the last rule has effect.

But I forgot to say that `inherit` doesn't work on IE7 and before. Then, you could use

```
rows[i].className+=' selected';
```

and

```
table.hovertable tr.selected{
   color:white;
   background:red;
}

table.hovertable tr.selected a:link{
   color:white
}
```

**Edit3:**

If you want to set the same styles to the cell with current month, you can do

```
var m=new Date().getMonth();
document.getElementById('months').rows[Math.floor(m/6)].cells[m%6].className+=' selected';
```

(suposing that the table has `id="months"`)

But then

```
table.hovertable .selected{
   color:white;
   background:red;
}

table.hovertable .selected a:link{
   color:white
}
```

(`.selected` instead of `tr.selected`, now it's a `td`).

But I see that you still use `color:inherit`. Now that you set the styles using classes you don't need it

Comment: Thanks Oriol.  Since the links on my page are generated dynamically and don't really exist in the rendered html, the css for links that you recommended isn't working because there are no html based links to apply the color to using this css.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @TedLederer But even if you create the links with javascript, they are HTML elements so CSS affects them.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for this page.  http://www.itsmyturnnow.com/HWC/BRP/08.htm.  You will see links on the regular browser page, but not in the source code.  I put the 'inherit' in my style sheet as recommended, but it is not affecting the color of the linked fonts in the table row.

Comment: @TedLederer See my edited post. The problem is that another rule overrides `inherit`

Comment: Thanks Oriol.  I added the css change.  In IE9 it makes the linked text color in the first cell white but in the next cell to the right, the font color remains black.  It is opposite in Chrome.  The second link color is changed, but not the first.  Any ideas?

Comment: My bad.  It was because they were visited links.  I have updated the CSS for this.  Thanks again Oriol!

Comment: Well, at the end you solved it alone. Sorry I didn't see your comments

Comment: Another quick question for you... @ http://www.itsmyturnnow.com/HWC/BRP/08.htm, at the top of the page I have 12 cells, 1 for each month.  When the page loads, I would like the cell that represents the current month to have its background color changed.  Can I fit something into the existing code above that would also do this for me?

Comment: Hi again.  Since my link color is set to 'inherit' in the css and 'white' in javascript, all of my links are turning white on hover.  I want to be able to change a specific set of linked text to blue on hover while the links that need to change to white on hover still do.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

rows[i].style.a.color should work. :link is not a real class.
would be easier if you show us rows[] and the content

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are having correct row[i] as html element present on page . Do `alert(row[i].id);` before you change color to make sure that you have correct element .

You can also do 
document.getElementsByTagName('ID' + i).style.color = 'red';

Actually its better to use css class for this kind of things . And doing with along with jquery will be easiest .

Comment: Everything I am doing works.  You can see it at http://www.itsmyturnnow.com/HWC/BRP/08.htm.  The only thing left is to find out the correct command for changing font colors with links.  You can see the full javascript and jquery code in the page source code at the bottom.

Comment: @TedLederer If you are looping right way that color will work fine . Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qpFSK/9/

Comment: Thanks Sonesh.  Now how would I incorporate your code into what I already have, so I continue to get the effect of the current day's row being dynamically highlighted and scrolled to if off the page?

Comment: I noticed in your example on jsfiddle.net that you have hyperlinks right in your html.  The links on my page are generated dynamically and so they don't actually show in the rendered code, so the code you suggested doesn't seem to work on my actual page.  Is there another way?  Since "rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'" & "rows[i].style.color = 'white'" worked to change their respective colors, I thought changing the link font color the same way would work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure why you are not using jquery when you are alrady using it to delay and animate . Still have a look at this code . http://jsfiddle.net/qpFSK/66/ . Put your required condition where needed . Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to work out what I needed with Oriol's help.  It works great in Firefox & Safari, we are just working out bugs for IE & Chrome... See jsfiddle.net/mannagod/SHa9X.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such simple solution. Links are child-elements of the row and do not follow the general Text Color. The simplest solution in my opinion would be to change the rows css class, and define the colors in there.

You can define a suitable block of colors like this in css:

```
.redHighlighted { background-color: 'red'; color: 'white'; }
.redHighlighted a, .redHighlighted a:visited,
.redHighlighted a:hover, .redHighlighted a:active { color: 'green'; }
```

And then you can do it in javascript with single line:

```
rows[i].setAttribute("class", "redHighlighted");
```

Later on you can of course just either remove the class, or replace it with something other.
Please also note, that you might have to specify the colors for TD elements, not rows in CSS like this:

```
.redHighlighted td { background-color: 'red'; color: 'white'; }
```